# ESP8266 Software serial to ATmega 328 is not properly working

Tags: esp8266, atmega328, softwareserial

Thanks in advance..

We are having esp8266-12E chip and Atmega328 connected as follows, 
ESP 12 pin as Tx,13 pin as Rx && Atmega328 13pin as Rx, 12pin as Tx. Everything works fine, but while communicating via serial some low pulse is being generated. We couldn't find the issue with multimeter anyway but got it by oscilloscope signal.

When this false low pulse during communication happens Atmega328 connected pins also getting low for the same duration.

We tried using separated logic execution for ESP and Atmega and both were worked perfectly, but only during communicating via Software serial its flickers getting started.

Please help us getting this resolved.

[image]

Comment: esp8266 SoftwareSerial doesn't work reliably

Comment: @Juraj: Thanks. Can I use default Tx and Rx? are those reliable?

Comment: yes of course. esp8266 has second hw Serial interface, but only TX of it can be used

Comment: That means I can transmit data to Atmega328 but could not get it back.

Comment: `low pulse is being generated` where is it being generated?

Comment: @jsotola, I read that esp8266 SoftwareSerial doesn't work reliably , but I never tested it. perhaps this 'low pulse' is an indices why it doesn't work. but I don't have time to investigate it

Comment: i did not ask a clear question .... the question is `which pin generates the low pulse?`

Comment: @jsotola, I wasn't clear too. connect an Uno to esp8266 over SoftwareSerial and you will know.

Comment: @jsotola, I did not say it will not work. It will work perfectly, but is not reliable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use SoftwareSerial in esp8266. Connect the 328p's SoftwareSerial pins to Serial interface pins of the esp8266. ESP8266 has second Serial interface named Serial1. It has only TX (io 2), but it is enough for debug prints.

To change the firmware or sketch in esp8266 you can use ArduinoOTA library, but you should be ready to disconnect the esp8266 Serial pins from the 328p and use them for Serial upload if the OTA upload fails.

You should use logic level converter from 5 V to 3.3 V to protect the esp8266 RX pin.

Comment: Many thanks Juraj. It’s solved our problem. Many many thanks as we are struggling with this quite many days.